# mysqli delete only working on second link click

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with all the articles looped out from the database along with a DELETE link that sends the ID of the post to the handler for deletion, but I have to click twice for it to delete.

Here's the deletion code in the handler:

```
if($_GET['deleteArticleId']){

    // Delete article
    $crudObject = new CrudClass();

    $row_id = $_GET['deleteArticleId'];

    $table_name = "28uge_cms_newsarticles";

    $crudObject->delete($table_name, $row_id);



    // Delete article links to categories
    $crudObject = new CrudClass();

    $sql = "DELETE FROM 28uge_cms_newsarticles_categories WHERE newsarticles_id = {$_GET['deleteArticleId']}";

    $crudObject->sendQueryToDatabase($sql);



    // Delete article links to images
    $crudObject = new CrudClass();

    $sql = "DELETE FROM 28uge_cms_newsarticles_images WHERE newsarticles_id = {$_GET['deleteArticleId']}";

    $crudObject->sendQueryToDatabase($sql);



    header('location: ../admin/newsview.php');
    exit;

}
```

"// Delete article links to categories" and "// Delete article links to images" works the first time around, but the "// Delete article" only works when the delete link has been pressed twice.

Here's the delete function code:

```
public function delete($table_name, $row_id){

    // Putting together the SQL string.
    $sql = "DELETE FROM $table_name WHERE id = $row_id";

    // Sending the SQL string off to the database.
    $this->dbConn -> query($sql);

}
```

I can't figure out what is causing this bug, so help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), and vulnerable to the [spider of doom](http://thedailywtf.com/articles/The_Spider_of_Doom)

Comment: Maybe you have a foreign_key costraint in the db, so with the first click you delete images and categories and with the second the article.

Comment: Out of the blue, if you have relationship bewteen your table and they are set to restrict. You will need to delete the childs records before the db let you delete the parent records. In your case, make sure you delete all the record assosiated to the article before deleting the actual article's record -OR- set your relationship to 'cascade' upon deletion.